# VSCode not autocompleting HTML tags in React

Tags: reactjs, editor, visual-studio-code

Before updating VSCode to the latest version (1.14, I had 1.13) when I was working on my React projects, I could type, for example, div + TAB key and it autocompleted . Also, If I typed div.row it autocompleted it to , but now it doesn't work anymore. When I type div and press the TAB key, it only indents the line. I have the HTML Snippets extension installed.

Does anyone how can I get the autocompletion to work like before?

Comment: "emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always",
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Visual Studio Code [1.14 introduced a new settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14#_editor) called `emmet.useNewEmmet` which defaults to `true`.

When set to `true` it'll per default disable the setting `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab`.

Changing `emmet.useNewEmmet` to `false` will re-enable the tab expansion.

However since the `useNewEmmet` settings is the way going forward, my recommendation is to keep `useNewEmmet` set as `true` but instead add two extra settings;

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    // any other languages you'd like
},
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always"
```

Restarting VS Code after adding these two will make the editor suggest Emmet abbreviations again and you'll have the same behavior as pre 1.14 release.

Comment: Wow. I spent quite a while trying to figure out what was going on. I found the includeLanguages setting, but apparently it was wrong (it was different than your suggestion). The good thing is that now it works like a charm again. Thank you Henrik!